# Pronunciation of "release"

Tags: pronunciation

My dictionary gives [rili:s], but I am hearing [rili:z] with firmly articulated "-z".
Does the pronunciation with "-s" really exist?

UPD:
Ok, probably it's a glitch in my ears, and I cannot distinguish final [s] and [z] well, but in the intervocalic position the sound is clearly different from s: compare "release a hostage" [z] vs "miss an opportunity" [s].

Comment: I have never heard the pronunciation you say hear. Where do you hear it and under what circumstances?

Comment: Yes, the -s pronunciation really does exist.  I never heard -z.

Comment: Did you mean to ask about realize?  Can you use the word in a sentence so we can be certain we know what word you are asking about?

Comment: Is it possible that you are speaking of speech in the American South? There is a persistent lexical variation of /z/ and /s/ in words like _greasy_, following a stressed vowel /i/ in this case, and preceding an unstressed vowel. In these areas (Midlands and Southern dialect groups), _greasy_ is pronounced /'ɡrizi/, and I have no doubt _release a_ would be pronounced /rɪ'lizə/. But only in the right phonological frame, mind.

Answer (score 1):

the pronunciation is actually with "s" not with "z"